# How to write dynamic xpath for a webElement?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, dynamic

I have gone through from a lot of question on stackoverflow but didn't find the solution for my problem

-There is an element on webpage which has text= "Success"
Now I want to locate that element, id of the elements keeps changing. There are some other elements with a similar name say - successful, unsuccessful, successfully etc.. on the same page but I want to search the particular element "Success". How should I do it? In this case,

> I don't think- startsWith() and contains() methods of XPath will work.

Comment: Can you share HTML code?

Comment: Use XPATH like, //div[contains(text(),'Success')] where you can replace div with the tag you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath to find it. i) //*[text()='Success'] or ii) //*[.='Success'].

Answer (score 0):

You can always use other attributes. You are not limited to id.
A few examples below:

**Basic xpath syntax:**

```
//tag[@tag-attribute='arrtibute-value']
//*[contains(@tag-attribute,'attribute-value')]
//tag[text()='inner-text']
//*[contains(text(),'inner-text')]
```

**Where:**
`tag` = the html tag
`*` = tag wildcard - matches any tag
`tag-attribute` = any attributes within the tag (name,id,class...)
`attribute-value` = the value of the specified tag-attribute

**Consider this sample:**

```
<div id="countryDiv1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="ConsignorAddressCountryId" tabindex="1" id="randomGenerated">Text1</button>
</div>

<div id="countryDiv2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="ConsignorAddressCountryId" tabindex="2" id="randomGenerated">Text2</button>
</div>
```

Here we have 2 buttons having the same random generated IDs but a few differences like `tabindex`, `inner text`, id of parent `div`.

**Sample xpath(s) for button 1:**

```
//button[@tabindex='1']
//button[@data-id='ConsignorAddressCountryId'][@tabindex='1']
//button[@data-id='ConsignorAddressCountryId'][text()='Text1']
//div[@id='countryDiv1']//button
```

Personally, I prefer using other attributes instead of text mainly because texts can have reserved characters that might mess up your xpath.

You can also check your xpath validity using the following:

Chrome Dev Tools (F12) > Elements Tab > Hit CTRL+F while under elements tab > paste your xpath > valid elements will be highlighted

Chrome Dev Tools (F12) > Console Tab > Enter: $x("yourxpath") > hit enter key > matching elements will be displayed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:-

```
 //*[@text()='Success']
```